# Ubuntu 20.04 install has no ipv6 sysctl directory

Tags: networking, 20.04, system

Quite literally, I'm seeing this:

```
$ ll /proc/sys/net/
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jul 30 17:04 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jul 30 17:04 ../
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jul 30 17:04 core/
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jul 30 17:04 ipv4/
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jul 30 17:04 netfilter/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 30 20:12 nf_conntrack_max
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jul 30 20:12 unix/
```

That's it. I would expect it to be there. Does something need to be set up, am I missing something?

Comment: We are missing info: do you have `ipv6` disabled in grub? or `/etc/sysctl.conf`?  or inside `/etc/sysctl.d/`? My system does have ipv6 and I did nothing to add it to /proc/sys/net ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Found no documentation anywhere that indicates any of these settings would suddenly remove the ipv6 directory from `/proc/sys/net/`. It should be there.